# Can a SSRS report contain double date/time parameters?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to have two date/time parameters in a report?

I have a simple dataset with the 'where' clause:

```
where RequestSource in (@reqsource)
and EntryDay between @startdate and @finishdate
and EntryDay between @periodstart and @periodend
```

In the report there is a calendar date/time parameter (using @startdate and @finishdate) and I wanted to add a second one (two part parameter) (using @periodstart and @periodend).

The dataset for the @periodstart parameter contains:

```
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as time, 'last quarter start' as timename
union all 
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as time, 'this quarter start' as timename
union all
select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as time, 'this year start' as timename
union all
select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as time, 'last year start' as timename
```

The dataset @periodend parameter contains:

```
select DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) as time, 'last quarter end' as timename
union all
select DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0)) as time, 'this quarter end' as timename
union all
select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) as time, 'this year end' as timename
union all
select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), -1) as time, 'last year end' as timename
```

Is it possible to have the @startdate and @finishdate parameters in null and use the @periodstart and @periodend parameters which have pre-defined values?

[report parameter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYyv1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your issue is, you are asking if it's possible to have more than one start date and end date?

Yes it is, you just need to accommodate this in your dataset query.

Unless I'm missing something I would do it something like this.

```
DECLARE @sDate datetime
DECLARE @eDate datetime

SET @sDate = ISNULL(@startdate, @periodstart)
SET @eDate = ISNULL(@finishdate, @periodend)

SELECT * 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE RequestSource IN (@reqsource)
        AND EntryDay BETWEEN @sDate AND @eDate
```